# Is there any possible to reset pickerview to start position?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i already put my `reloadAllComponents` inside `didSelectRow` of pickerview but it can't reset my pickerview position to start position. is there any possible to reset my pickerview to start position after user selecting data because i use 1 pickerview as an input for many button.
What code should i write and where to write it?

I hope you understand my english. Thank you.

I already put code but it still can't put my pickerView state to start position.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    year = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    month = [picker selectedRowInComponent:1];
    day = [picker selectedRowInComponent:2];
    date = @"";
    if(viewPicker.tag == 1) {
        labelTime.text = [date stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", year , month, day];
    else {
       ...
    }
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`reloadAllComponents` method just queries your datasource in order to synchronize the data with the picker. If by 'resetting' you mean that you want you picker to move its current selection to the first row you can do something like this:

```
// Here we select the first row, in the first component with animation
// Customize it accordingly
[myPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

Although be careful. If you call this method in `didSelectRow` then every time the user selects a row, the picker will go to the first row automatically...

Comment: i did it but still can't move to start position. please teach me.

Comment: As I said, there is probably not a good idea to call `selectRow` inside `didSelectRow` (it will fire **every** time a component is settled on a new value). Also, have you set your picker's delegate (in other words, are you sure that `didSelectRow` is called?)?